# How to disable time sync with Windows 7 as host OS in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, sync, date-time

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 with VirtualBox running the same 64 bit Windows 7 as a guest OS.

When I set a specific date and time, it will always revert to the host OS’s date and time on startup. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Find the location where your Virtual Machine is stored. You can do this by right clicking on the machine from the list in the VirtualBox Manager and selecting **Show in Explorer**

[image: Find Machine Source Path]

2. Backup the file called ***yourVMname*.vbox**
3. Open the file in a text editor and navigate to the **`<ExtraData>`** element which should contain a list of **`ExtraDataItem`** elements
4. Add the following item to the list: 
   **`<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" value="1"/>`**
5. The final section should look something like this:

[image: Final Edited VM Configuration]

[source](http://stevenormrod.com/2012/10/disabling-time-sync-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: Vbox show me issue with first quotation mark you have used. After I type it manually it worked.

Comment: I did it on Mac, it worked. I just replaces VBoxInternal by VBoxInternal2.

Comment: VirtualBox should be restarted.

Comment: This did not work for me on MacOS:Mojave using Vbox 6.0.6. After editing and saving the `.vbox` file, starting the VM would revert to the previous state without my changes. The answer by @Triple_Fault did the trick.

Comment: To avoid VBox from restoring changes, close all VirtualBox windows and delete .vbox-prev file, which usually is located together with .vbox file.

Answer (score 19):

The command to disable time synchronization between host and guest in Virtualbox is:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

See the Virtualbox manual, section 9.14, especially 9.14.4.

Note that in a Windows host your command window's default directory must be in the directory where Vboxmanage.exe exists (default: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox) or you have to type the full path to Vboxmanage.exe.

Comment: Also `vagrant reload` after running that set command.

Comment: This is better than modifying the `.vbox` directly.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Catalina

Comment: On Windows, you can also add your VirtualBox installation directory to your PATH environment variable. This will let you use `VBoxManage` without needing to be in the installation directory or to use the executable's full path.